# Deep cloning entity from one org to another

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

So, yet another fun task at hand.

We have created a windows service to keep some records in sync between 2 CRM 2011 orgs in production.

We have looked into deep cloning which is what we want, but it appears that it's deep cloning the EntityReference, not the actual Entity.

Any ideas, advice, etc would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I am successfully deep cloning with this code:

I use the XRM service context, copy the clone to a new entity, remove the attributes which designate it as an already existing entitiy (such as the primary key, etc) set up the relationships to existing entities, then send it to the create method. I have to explicitly do the same for all related entities (which I have done for webfiles and notes, in my example)

```
        var clonedwebpage = ((Entity)webpage).Clone(true);

        clonedwebpage.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        clonedwebpage.Attributes.Remove("adx_webpageid");
        //clonedwebpage.Attributes.Remove("adx_pagetemplateid");
        clonedwebpage.EntityState = null;
        clonedwebpage["adx_websiteid"] = new EntityReference("adx_webpage",livesiteGuid);
        //clonedwebpage["adx_parentpageid"] = 
        // create the template guid
        Guid tempGuid = new Guid(templateguid);
        clonedwebpage["adx_pagetemplateid"] = new EntityReference("adx_pagetemplate",tempGuid); // set the template of the new clone


        //serviceContext.Attach(cloned);
        //serviceContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

        Guid clonedwebpageguid = _service.Create(clonedwebpage);

         //var webpage = serviceContext.Adx_webpageSet.Where(wp => wp.Id == webpageguid).First();
        //var notes_webile = serviceContext.Adx_webfileSet.Where(wf => wf.








        //*********************************** WEB FILE *********************************************
        foreach (var webfile in webpage.adx_webpage_webfile)
        {
            var cloned_webfile = webfile.Clone(); 

            //should iterate through every web file that is related to a web page, and clone it. 
            cloned_webfile.Attributes.Remove("adx_webfileid");
            cloned_webfile.Attributes.Remove("adx_websiteid");
            cloned_webfile.Attributes.Remove("adx_parentpageid");
            cloned_webfile["adx_websiteid"] = new EntityReference("adx_website", livesiteGuid);
            cloned_webfile["adx_parentpageid"] = new EntityReference("adx_webpage", clonedwebpageguid);
            cloned_webfile.EntityState = null;
            cloned_webfile.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid ClonedWebFileGuid = _service.Create(cloned_webfile);

            //*********************************** NOTE *********************************************
            foreach (var note in webfile.adx_webfile_Annotations)
            {

                var cloned_note = note.Clone();

                cloned_note.Attributes.Remove("annotationid"); // pk of note
                cloned_note.Attributes.Remove("objectid"); // set to web file guid

                cloned_note["objectid"] = new EntityReference("adx_webfile", ClonedWebFileGuid); // set the relationship between our newly cloned webfile and the note
                cloned_note.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                cloned_note.EntityState = null;

                Guid clonednote = _service.Create(cloned_note);


                //cloned_note.Attributes.Remove("ownerid");
                //cloned_note.Attributes.Remove("owningbusinessunit");
                //cloned_note.Attributes.Remove("owningteam");
                //cloned_note.Attributes.Remove("owninguser");


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't use this with dynamics, but when we need a deep copy, we serialize the object using BinaryFormatter, then deserialize it into a new object, which is very similar to what happens with .Net remoting.

Here is our VB.Net solution (I can convert to C# if desired):

```
''' <summary>
''' This method clones all of the items and serializable properties of the current collection by 
''' serializing the current object to memory, then deserializing it as a new object. This will 
''' ensure that all references are cleaned up.
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function CreateSerializedCopy(Of T)(ByVal oRecordToCopy As T) As T
    ' Exceptions are handled by the caller

    If oRecordToCopy Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    If Not oRecordToCopy.GetType.IsSerializable Then
        Throw New ArgumentException(oRecordToCopy.GetType.ToString & " is not serializable")
    End If

    Dim oFormatter As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter

    Using oStream As IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream
        oFormatter.Serialize(oStream, oRecordToCopy)
        oStream.Position = 0
        Return DirectCast(oFormatter.Deserialize(oStream), T)
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The serialize/de-serialize route sounds good to me. Could you provide any examples? Like how "deep" you can tell it to clone and how to get it into the other org from a serialized format. Thanks.

Comment: @JonC: I added our VB code as an example. It will serialize the entire object tree, but it also will call the serialization constructors and GetData methods on each object, so you have an opportunity to change information as needed. I'm not entirely clear on what is involved with changing orgs since we don't use CRM, but this is the solution we use for general .net objects.